# What should my model look like for a simplified Stack Overflow questionn&answers page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, design-patterns, view, model

I am trying out MVC for the first time and I am trying to build a very simplified version of StackOverflow. I have Models/database tables like:

```
Users
Questions
Answers
Comments
```

and some ViewModels of these Models which I use for the Views. 
The relations between the models are:

```
Users 1:m  with Questin, Answers, Comments
Questions 1:m with Answers, Comments
Answers 1:m with Comments
```

and

```
Users m:m Questions
Users m:m Answers
```

for votes.

What should my ViewModel look like for the Question page, which is the same as this page that you are currently reading this from?
The page should be something like:

-----------------------
Question

Answer
Answer
...
Answer

form for answering the question only for logged in users
-----------------------
and list of comments under the Question and the answers

I come up with this:

```
public class QuestiongView
{
   public QuestionShort question { get; set;}
   public IEnumerable<AnswerShort> answers { get; set;}
   public AnswerWritabelByUser answerByUser {get; set;}  // only for logged in usesr. This is where you type your answer
}
```

and `QuestionShort` and `AnswerShort` are classes which have `List<Comments>` in them. 
For voting i would use $.ajax calls.


With what i have learned so far i think this is the right way to do it, but it seems messy as well. Maybe i will use partial view to clean up the code in the View.

So, is this the correct way of implementing MVC, do you have some suggestions of improving my whole approach for this particular problem, do I know what am i talking about or have i missed the whole design pattern/ concept of MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something very close to:

**Models**

```
public QuestionViewModel : IQuestionViewModel
{
  public QuestionModel : Question { get; set; }
}

public IQuestionViewModel
{
  QuestionModel: Question { get; }
}

public QuestionModel : IAnswersViewModel, ICommentsViewModel, IUserViewModel
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Summary { get; set; }
  public IENumerable<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
  public UserModel User { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<AnswerModel> Answers { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<CommentModel> Comments { get; set; }
}

public IAnswersViewModel
{
  IEnumerable<AnswerModel> Answers { get; }
}

public ICommentsViewModel
{
  IEnumerable<CommentModel> Comments { get; }
}

public IUserViewModel
{
  UserModel User { get; }
}

public AnswerModel : ICommentsViewModel, IUserViewModel
{
  public Summary { get; set; }
  public UserModel { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<CommentModel> Comments { get; set; }
}

public CommentModel : IUserViewModel
{
  public string Summary { get; set; }
  public UserModel User { get; set; }
}

public UserModel 
{
  public string Name { get; set ; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class QuestionController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Details(int QuestionID)
  {
    // Populate the model as you see fit
    // I normally have my models populate themselves
    // So I don't duplicate code in my controllers

    QuestionViewModel model = QuestionViewModel.Get(QuestionID)

    if (model == null)
    {
      return this.UnavailableQuestion()
    }

    return this.View(model);
  }

  // Questions that don't exist
  public ActionResult UnavailableQuestion
  {
    return this.View();
  }
}
```

** Views (All VERY simplified)**

*Question\Details.cshtml*

```
@Model IQuestionViewModel

@model.Question.Title

@model.Question.Summary

@html.Partial("partial-UserComplex", model.Question)

@html.Partial("partial-Comments", model.Question)

@html.Partial("partial-Answers", model.Question);
```

*Shared\partial-UserComplex.cshtml*

```
@Model IUserViewModel   

//Complex might display details like points, etc etc
@model.User.Name
```

*Shared\partial-UserSimple.cshtml*

```
@Model IUserViewModel   

//Simple would just have a name with a link to profile
@model.User.Name
```

*Shared\partial-Comments.cshtml*

```
@Model ICommentsViewModel

@foreach (CommentModel comment in model.Comments)
{
  @comment.Summary
  @Html.Partial("partial-UserSimple", comment)
}
```

*Question\partial-Answers.cshtml*

```
@Model IAnswersViewModel

@foreach (AnswerModel answer in model.Answers)
{
  @answer.Summary

  @Html.Partial("partial-UserComplex", answer)

  @Html.Partial("partial-Comments", answer)
}
```

**PROS**

- Each View/PartialView is using an interface so I can create as many different models I want and reuse the same view.
- Since displaying Comments(Maybe?) and Users will be all over the site, I can easily reuse the partials in the shared directory
- Displaying Answers, Comments, and Users is completely decoupled from each other.
- Very extensible.

**CONS**

- Using Interfaces in Views is a little complex because anything new you want to add you have to add to interface AND any class the inherits the interface.
- This is fairly complex based on the number of subclasses and reuse of models.

Comment: Thank's Erik this is an excellent answer, it really  speed up the development.